# How to have an image instead of a string inserted into GridView that uses a data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is homework, a Website to rate doctors, using Visual Studio in C#.  I have a GridView that gets data from a repository.  The DoctorPicture column should display a picture that is in my Images folder, not a string.  When I run the page with the GridView, an error says, "A field or property with the name 'Images' was not found on the selected data source."  This is my GridView:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceDoctor" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="MidtermApplication.Models.Doctor" DeleteMethod="Remove" InsertMethod="Add" SelectMethod="GetItems" TypeName="MidtermApplication.Models.TestDoctorRepository" UpdateMethod="Update"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewDoctor" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceDoctor" DataKeyNames="DoctorPicture" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorName" HeaderText="DoctorName" SortExpression="DoctorName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorSpecialty" HeaderText="DoctorSpecialty" SortExpression="DoctorSpecialty" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="rating" HeaderText="rating" SortExpression="rating" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="times" HeaderText="times" SortExpression="times" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="fave" HeaderText="fave" SortExpression="fave" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="rated" HeaderText="rated" SortExpression="rated" />
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Images" HeaderText="DoctorPicture">
            </asp:ImageField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is where the data is coming from (I think):

```
public class TestDoctorRepository : IDoctorRepository
    {
        List<Doctor> doctors;

        public TestDoctorRepository()
        {
            doctors = new List<Doctor> {
                new Doctor { DoctorPicture = "Images/0cropped.jpg", DoctorName = "Michael Shores", DoctorSpecialty = "Opthamology", times = 0, rating = 0, rated = true, fave = true },
                new Doctor { DoctorPicture = "Images/1cropped.jpg", DoctorName = "Ming Wu", DoctorSpecialty = "Cardiology", times = 0, rating = 0, rated = true, fave = true },
                new Doctor { DoctorPicture = "Images/1bcropped.jpg", DoctorName = "Susan McInerney", DoctorSpecialty = "Gynecology", times = 0, rating = 0, rated = true, fave = true },
                new Doctor { DoctorPicture = "Images/2cropped.jpg", DoctorName = "Michelle Adkins", DoctorSpecialty = "Dermatology", times = 0, rating = 0, rated = true, fave = true },
                new Doctor { DoctorPicture = "Images/5cropped.jpg", DoctorName = "Kathy Powers", DoctorSpecialty = "Chiropractor", times = 0, rating = 0, rated = true, fave = true }

            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "A field or property with the name 'Images' was not found on the
>   selected data source."

Error explains the reason, if there is no 'Images' property then which property can be set as `DataImageUrlField`?

try by changing `DataImageUrlField="Images"` to `DataImageUrlField="DoctorPicture"`

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="DoctorPicture" HeaderText="DoctorPicture">
```